# Include files from the App_Data checkbox missing

Tags: visual-studio-2012, publishing-site

I'm running the Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate download from MSDN on my home laptop but it is missing the "Include files from the App_Data" check box that I see on my work PC when I go to Publish... Any idea what I have to do to get that box? I know I can publish from the command line but it's easier from the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the version of the Azure SDK and it appeared.